# Websharper, Sitelets and Forms

Tags: html, forms, f#, websharper

I've been trying to create a form using Websharper to collect user input. So far I've identified three actions for my site:

```
type MyAction =
    | [<CompiledName "">] Index
    | [<Method "POST">] GetUser of username : string
    | Stats of username: string
```

Using Sitelet.Infer I've managed to implement basic UI, but I have no idea how to refer to the content of my input box (usernameInput):

```
Sitelet.Infer <| function
    | Index ->
        Content.PageContent <| fun ctx ->
            let usernameInput= Input [Text ""]
            { Page.Default with
                Title = Some "Welcome!"
                Body = 
                    [ 
                        Div [
                            Form
                                [
                                    usernameInput-< [Name "username" ]
                                    Input [Value "Request"] -< [Type "submit" ]

                                ] -< [ Attr.Action (ctx.Link (* GetUser usernameInput.Content *) ); Method "POST" ]
                        ]
                    ]
            }
    | GetUser username ->
        Content.Redirect <| Stats username
    | Stats username ->
        Content.PageContent <| fun ctx ->
            { Page.Default with
                Body = [Text ("Stats for " + username)] }
```

I noticed usernameInput doesn't have any field like "Value" or so and I guess either it needs casting or I'm doing something wrong.

I would prefer not to use JavaScript in my code (Is it possible to mix Html.Server and Html.Client Elements in a Sitelet at all ?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form POST data is not passed via the URL, so you cannot pass it with `ctx.Link`. It is automatically passed via the request body, with a format similar to GET query arguments (for example in your case, `username=myusername`). This is currently not parsed by `Sitelet.Infer`, although we will probably add it in the future. For now you can use an action without arguments and then extract the data from the request:

```
type MyAction =
    | [<Method "POST">] GetUser
    | // ...

Sitelet.Infer <| function
    | GetUser ->
        Content.CustomContentAsync <| fun ctx ->
            match ctx.Request.Post.["username"] with
            | None -> Content.NotFound
            | Some username -> Content.Redirect <| Stats username
            |> Content.ToResponseAsync ctx
    | // ...
```

Comment: I implemented this, but the dictionary ctx.Request.Post.[] contains no values (i.e. everytime it hits the "None" case in pattern matching above; I've debugged into it and noticed there are no values in the ctx.Request.Post).
Is there anything else I need to do in order to make it working ?

Comment: Something to add: my browser shows that the generated POST request contains "username" value, but somehow ctx (on F# side) doesn't.

Comment: OK - I've got the answer here:
http://websharper.com/question/79205/ctx-request-post-missing-parameters